# How Fit the pdf page of different size to the screen of the iPad?

Tags: iphone, ipad

Hello i am working on a pdf reader application.I have used tiled layer to render PDF but i am getting my page shifted to upside down according to size of the pfd file size.Please suggest me a way to fit my page to the screen automatically.Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple way to read a PDF in iPhone/iPad:

1. Take one UIwebView (name:pdfView).
2. Give Iboutlet connection to it & Delegate it to FilesOwner
3. In Viewdidload

   ```
   [self.pdfView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ObjC" ofType:@"pdf"]]]];
   ```
4. ObjC.pdf should be in resource folder..
   Now  to Fit the pdf page of different size to the screen of the iPad
   just open respective .xib file then go to inspector of UIwebView
   then web view attributes and there tick mark scales page to fit
   option.

Comment: if i do in this manner i am getting the pdf content only up to certain portion of the UIWebView even web view is fit to the screen.I want to fill the pdf content to screen not the web view.

Comment: once again check the size of UIWebView to fit to the device screen and    scales page to fit option in web view attributes in inspector window.  I was also have the same problem but in this way its resolved. Let me know if your problem is resolved or not ?